# vue js how to validate the particular routes for the particular roles

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

In my application User wants the ability to create a role from the interface, and assign the pages to the role. Which Means both roles and routes are dynamic.

Here in the [example](https://medium.com/@kelin2025/a-few-thoughts-about-that-87c617408489) the routes to the roles are defined in the client. Where we have to assume that the user must be in the certain roles to be allowed to access that page. But I don't know which role needs to be assigned to that pages?

Currently what I know is that we can check the whether the user is authenticated or not before accessing the page, but I am obstructing in the logic to check whether the pages are not accessible to the user with the particular roles.

As i know that i can validate the routes logic using

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   //how to validate 
})
```

Currently, my pages look like below

```
items: [
    {
      name: 'Dashboard',
      url: '/dashboard',
      icon: 'icon-speedometer'
    },
    {
      name: 'Base',
      url: '/base',
      icon: 'icon-puzzle',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Cards',
          url: '/base/cards',
          icon: 'icon-puzzle'
        },
        {
          name: 'Forms',
          url: '/base/forms',
          icon: 'icon-puzzle'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I also have other information on the client side.

```
DisplayPicture
FullName
Role
RoleHierarchy
RoleId
UserId
```

Can you guide me to the logic on how to verify whether the pages are accessible to the roles or not?

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: can you help me something related with the scenario using `router.beforeEach((to, from, next)` which some start up code

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using to check whether the page is accessible to current user or not.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Permission based routing
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.conditionalRoute)) {
    if (to.name === 'Administration') {
      if (hasRole('Admin')) {
        next()
      }
    }
    next(false)
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

In above example if name of the to.name is "Administration" then check if current user's role is "Admin" or redirect him back to previous page.

You also need to add  `meta: {conditionalRoute: true}` to your routes where you need to apply conditional routing.

Comment: I will not have just admin the role may be anything. Is it okay to check only with Admin? Can you explain me what the method `hasRole` do?

Comment: Has role is a function I have written to return role of the current user.